# WCF; Client error when adding service reference: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, nettcpbinding

I have this WCF service which is deployed to windows service:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        
        internal static ServiceHost service = null;
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

            INotificationServiceMode mode = new TcpChatServiceMode();
            
            
            
            try
            {
                service = new ServiceHost(typeof(NotificationService), new Uri("http://localhost:8000/Notification"), new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:808/Notification"));
                // Add service behavior

                NetTcpBinding tcp = new NetTcpBinding();

                service.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(INotificationService), tcp, "net.tcp://localhost:808/Notification");

                ServiceMetadataBehavior metaBehavior = service.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();

                if (metaBehavior == null)
                {
                    metaBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                    metaBehavior.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
                    metaBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;

                    service.Description.Behaviors.Add(metaBehavior);
                    service.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");
                }


                service.Open();
               
            }
            catch (CommunicationException communicationException)
            {
                throw communicationException;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw exception;
            }
            finally
            {
                service.Abort();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            service.Close();
        }
    }
```

The consumer application gets error

```
Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost/Notification/mex. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:04.0952640. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:808.
```

[image]

What is wrong with that? I am pretty sure that the service is running because when I enabled `net.tcp` protocol in IIS I got an error that the port is already used by another process

Comment: The error message you post indicates that the port is already occupied by another program. You can first check whether port 808 is occupied, and then check the firewall Settings.